# How to set the optimal value to a trigger signal?

Tags: distributions, optimization, quantiles, frequency

I have an indicator which oscillates between -50 and +50 values.
Then I have to set a optimal signal value to go long or short.

I've thought in something like this:

```
if (indicator > ((50 / indicator.mean()) * 1.25)) and (isIncreasing(indicator) == True):
    # go long!
elif (indicator < ((-50 / indicator.mean()) * 0.75)) and (isDecreasing(indicator) == True):
    # go short!
else:
    # chillax
```

Therefore, to sum it up:

- The mean is usually round -5 and +5, ish.
- If the indicator is 25% above of the max/mean, and is increasing: go long.
- If the indicator is 25% below of the min/mean, and is decreasing: go short.
- If none of previous conditions were triggered, then take a coffee. :)

The point is to stop before the indicator change its direction.
But, as you see, the previous formula is merely intuitive. And what if the mean is zero? Then I would have problems in the division...

So there is any formula to calculate the optimal value to place my signal, in order to prevent go long and immediately after a decrease of my indicator? May be using some kind of pattern regression which calculates the following movement?

Comment: How strongly does the mean vary over time? Do you repeatedly compute a new mean (such as in a window) or do you use a fix value computed once? Why would you not simply use the percentiles 0.25 and 0.75 as thresholds?

Comment: Yes, you're right: I use a window of 60 in order to update the mean over time. But, the problem is that the mean could be 0.02 and suddenly the indicators raises up till 10.00. I don't want to calc just the percentile, because the max and the min are approximate values, I mean, the indicator could have a value of 64.0, but it is not very frequent.

Comment: If you could present the problem that you wish to solve/ the behaviour you wish to achieve, maybe one could more easily provide a solution. Your current solution suffers from division by 0 and does not seem feasible therefore. What does the indicator do, why does it act like it does and what do you wish to achieve such as "go long", "go short". Finally, why did you chose max/mean and min/mean (which does seems rather odd since mean could be negative or positive and therefore the threshold can switch sides)